# backup sql database from .bak file from another server

Tags: sql-server-2005, import, database-backups

I am working with this error for sometime now.

[image]

"Failed with the operaring System Error 21 (The device is not ready.)"

I scourged the internet but could not find the solution. Here are the links that look at
I am using [this tutorial](http://cephas.net/blog/2003/05/14/restoring-a-bak-file-to-a-sql-server-database/) for importing the database (.bak) while which was exported from another machine and copied to mine.

[On this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/517f967c-7fa3-4d5f-a36b-d7b15c7f93ff/) the very last paragraph is very helpful but it did not work for me.

I looked for other links and tried their solution, those did not work either.

I changed directory permission and allowed full access to everyone, that did not work. I also copy that .bak files to the other back databases that I have (and which imports fine), that still did not work.

Am I missing something simple, permission etc?

I am using SQL Server 2005 with SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this was a security feature.

I could not restore the database into a name other than its original name which I was trying to do. But I could restore back on the same system into a different name. What I did is back my current database and restored them in different names that I wanted.

Right click on the original database and click restore. In this case do not change the name of the database or any parameters, it should now work.

I would also be caution to allow *everyone* in the directy where the backups are copied and give *everyone" object full control of the folder.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a warning that you're saving the file(s) into a location that doesn't exist on that particular SQL Server workstation.  For instance, if you backup a database on one machine containing an "E:\SQL_Databases" folder, and then transfer the .bak file to a machine containing only one hard drive designated as "C:\". SQL Server "remembers" where the .mdf, .ldf. and .ndf files resided on the first machine and tries to restore them to the same place. So make sure the location to which you are restoring the .mdf, etc. actually exists on the new machine. If everything doesn't match exacty, you receive this error.